# Structures for random graphs with structure

Tags: graph-theory, random-graphs, tiling

**Background**
<sup>*[You may skip this and go immediately to the Definitions.]*</sup>

Crucial features of a (random) graph or network are:

- the degree distribution $p(d)$ (exponential, Poisson, or power law)
- the mean degree $\bar{d}$
- the mean [clustering coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clustering_coefficient#Network_average_clustering_coefficient) $\bar{C}$
- the mean distance $L$ and diameter $D$

Randomly generated graphs often are required to exhibit the [small-world property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-world_network), i.e. $L\propto \log N$  and $\bar{C}$ is “not small”. There are several random graph models that address at least one of these conditions:

- The [Watts-Strogatz model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts_and_Strogatz_model) (with underlying regular ring lattice)
- The [Barabasi-Albert model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barab%C3%A1si%E2%80%93Albert_model) (with preferred attachment)
- The [Configuration model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model) (with given degree sequences, resp. distributions)
- The [Newman model](https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.4009) (incorporating [community structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Community_structure))

While the Watts-Strogatz and the Barabasi-Albert model are modifications of the [Erdős–Rényi model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erd%C5%91s%E2%80%93R%C3%A9nyi_model), and the Newman model is a specific generalization of the configuration model, I wonder if there is already a "meta-model" that tries to incorporate the best of all of these models. (Reference request.)

Generalizing both Watts-Strogatz's and Newman's model, I'd like to investigate random graphs that *"interpolate between a randomized structure close to ER graphs and **[some arbitrary regular graph]**"* (quote from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watts%E2%80%93Strogatz_model#Rationale_for_the_model)).

For this, I'd like to have at hand a multitude of regular graphs which can

- be systematically symbolized and enumerated,
- be easily generated from their symbol (i.e. their adjacency matrices), and
- possibly have closed form expressions for the small-world characteristics $L$ and $\bar{C}$

Which regular graphs I have in mind can most easily be explained by an example.

---

**Definitions**

Let a vertex configuration be a graph that represents a vertex $\nu$ with a number of immediate neighbours $\nu_0,\nu_2,\dots,\nu_{d-1}$ and a shortest path (of arbitrary length) between each pair of consecutive neighbours $\nu_i, \nu_{i+1}$. A vertex configuration can be codified by the symbol $(n_1.n_2.\dots.n_k)^m$ which tells, that $\nu$ has degree $d = m \cdot k$ and is surrounded by an $m$-periodic sequence of $n_i$-faces resp. shortest cycles. (This is nothing but the standard definition of [vertex configurations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_configuration) in geometry in the language of graph theory.)

Example:

[image] $(4)^4$

A vertex is said to have a given vertex configuration $\Gamma$ when its neighbourhood together with one shortest path between neighbours is isomorphic to $\Gamma$. A graph is said to have a given vertex configuration $\Gamma$ when all of its vertices have vertex configuration $\Gamma$. A vertex configuration is said to be realizable when there is a graph that has it.

Now consider finite graphs in which all vertices have the same vertex configuration.

**Questions**

> 1. Are all vertex configurations $\Gamma$ realizable by graphs of more or less arbitrary size? How to prove or disprove this?
>    <sup>This has to do with the question if all vertex configurations (in the sense of geometry) which don't define a periodic tiling of the sphere (i.e. a regular polyhedron) define a periodic tiling of the Euclidean or hyperbolic plane.</sup>
> 2. If there are non-realizable vertex configurations: How do I check if a given vertex configuration is realizable?
> 3. Does a graph with a given vertex configuration $\Gamma$ have to be vertex-transitive?
> 4. Since the (equal) number of vertices of two vertex-transitive graphs with the same vertex configuration doesn't guarantee that they are isomorphic: By which general means can their "shape" be defined, so that two equally defined graphs must be isomorphic? (For an example: see below.)
> 5. Is there a systematic way to generate an adjacency matrix for a given realizable vertex configuration and "shape"?

With "shape" I mean what Dolbilin and Schulte call "neighborhood complexes (coronas)" in their paper [The Local Theorem for Monotypic Tilings](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i2r7/pdf).

---

**Examples**

Consider the vertex configuration $(4)^4$ and a "shape" defined by numbers $(4, 6)$

[image] [image]

When linking vertices on opposite sides of the shape all vertices have the same vertex configuration $(4)^4$, moreover the resulting graph is vertex-transitive:

[image] [image]

We find diameter $D = 5$, clustering coefficient $\bar{C} = 0$, and mean distance $L =\frac{1}{23}(4\times 1 + 7 \times 2 + 7 \times 3 + 4 \times 4 + 1 \times 5) \approx  2.61$ for which to find a closed or recursive explicit expression (depending on $(n,m)$) seems to be feasible.

For the "shape"

[image: ![enter image description here] [image]

with the same vertex configuration and number of vertices we find $D = 5$ and mean distance $L =\frac{1}{23}(4\times 1 + 6 \times 2 + 6 \times 3 + 5 \times 4 + 2 \times 5) \approx  2.78$

For the "shape"

[image] [image]

with roughly the same number of vertices we find $D = 4$ and mean distance $L =\frac{1}{24}(4\times 1 + 8 \times 2 + 8 \times 3 + 4 \times 4 ) \approx  2.5$.

If you want a cluster coefficient $\bar{C} = 1/2$ you can start with a vertex configuration $(3.n)^m$, e.g. $(3.4)^2$:

[image]

Unfortunately, this configuration does not qualify because it doesn't tile a plane but the sphere (giving rise to the [cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron)). So you have to choose $(3.4)^3$ at least. To draw a nice "shape" of some size that can be made into a finite graph with vertex configuration $(3.4)^m$, $m > 2$, requires [hyperbolic geometry](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3790703/1792). To find an adjacency matrix is even harder, as I guess (see question 5). Also the diameter $D$ and mean distance $L$ (as closed expressions).

Alternatively, one can add an edge to half of the $n\cdot m$ $4$-cycles (randomly chosen) of the $(4)^4$ graph - thus reducing diameter $D$ and mean distance $L$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following vertex configuration has notation $(3.4.4.4)^1$ and should provide counterexamples to question 1 (existence of graphs of arbitrary size) and question 3 (vertex-transitivity).

[image]

There are only finitely many graphs that realize this configuration, and all of them are finite with at most 24 vertices. Exactly two of them are planar, the edge-graph of [rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rhombicuboctahedron) (left), and the edge-graph of the closely related [pseudo-rhombicuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elongated_square_gyrobicupola) (right).
Only the first one is vertex-transitive.

[image]

All other graphs can be obtained from these by identifying vertices.
For example, identifying antipodal vertices in the left graph gives a "projective polyhedron":

[image]

I highlighted the vertex configuration in the right image because it is not obvious in this drawing.

I think these are all the graphs with this configuration. I might be wrong, but there are certainly no such graphs with more than 24 vertices.

---

More generally, you might be interested in the *Local Theorem* from

- ["The Local Theorem for Monotypic Tilings"](https://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v11i2r7/pdf) by Dolbilin and Schulte

which is concerned with the question when certain local restrictions imply global symmetry. Usually, it gives uniqueness and vertex-transitivity, but it only applies if the topology is "simply connected" (so, for tilings of the sphere, Euclidean/hyperbolic plane, but not for the torus, as you have seen in your question that the graph is not unique for $(4)^4$).

In the start of Section 3 (below Theorem 3.1) they state that the configuration $(3.5.5.5)^1$ can be realized as an infinite graph, but not as a vertex-transitive one. I have tried to track down this claim, but they only refer to the book "Tilings and Patterns" which contains literally thousands of tilings, and I was not able to find the desired one.

---

Finally, the following configuration $(3.4.5)^1$ should not be realizable at all:

[image]

To see this, note that the graph must contain a "triangular face" (since the configuration does).
Each of the three edges of that triangle is shared either with a quadrangle, or a pentagon. W.l.o.g. assume that two edges are shared with a quadrange. But these two edges share a vertex, and so this vertex cannot be of type $(3.4.5)^1$.

In general it seems quite tricky to distinguish the realizable from the non-realizable configurations.
As a rule of thumb, it seems that odd-faces pose a problem, similarly as they did in the previous example.
So, e.g. a configuration $(\mathbf 5.8.10)^1$ cannot exist either for the same reason, as there is a pentagonal face that bounds two different kinds of faces, and there is no face-type repeated at a vertex.

---

Since you mention (in the comments) that you are mostly interested in $(3.n)^m$ (assuming $n\ge 3$, $m\ge 2$):

> This configuration always exists, is unique and vertex-transitive  (assuming a "simply connected topology", which we can translate as "the graph is planar").
>
> It is finite only for $(3.3)^2$ ([octahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octahedron)), $(3.4)^2$ ([cuboctahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cuboctahedron)) and $(3.5)^2$ ([icosidodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosidodecahedron)). You can consider it "planar" for $\smash{(3.3)^3}$ ([triangular tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_tiling)) and $\smash{(3.6)^2}$ ([trihexagonal tiling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trihexagonal_tiling)), and hyperbolic in all other cases.

The uniqueness and symmetry is essentially a consequence of the Local Theorem (and the related Extension Theorem) mentioned before. But in easy terms: if you try to build a graph with such a vertex configuration, and you start from any vertex, and then you try to complete the vertex configuration around any of the other vertices, you can do this only in a unique way (really, try it on paper). Since you make no choice in any (of the possibly infinitely many) steps, the result is unique.

Comment: Thanks, your answer is relevant in two respects: First, it shows that a graph that realizes a configuration doesn't have to be vertex-transitive. (That's important for me to know, and it answers question 3) Second it shows that there are (of course) configurations that tile only the sphere (defining a polyhedron) but not a plane. This case was excluded in the remark to question 1.

Comment: Do you have a tool at hand that draws graphs for given configurations?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Sadly no, I always do it by hand.

Comment: As I do .......;-)

Comment: Thanks for the hint to the Dolbilin-Schulte paper!

Comment: And thanks a lot for the counter example! This was my impression, too: that it is tricky to check a configuration for realizability. By the way: I always tended to consider only "tame" configurations of the form $(3.n)^m$ - these should work. Or do some of them don't pass your rule-of-thumb test?

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker The graph with configuration $(3.n)^m$ exists, is unique and vertex-transitive. I edited my answer.

Comment: Note that $(3.3)^3 = (3)^6$. Note further that $(6)^3$ gives rise to the hexagonal tiling (which you know for sure).

Comment: @Hans-PeterStricker Okay, uniqueness is a lie. Imagine that you can build finite graphs of type $(3.3)^3$ by wrapping around the tiling to a torus as you did with $(4)^4$. The Local Theorm assumes that the "topology is simply connected" (e.g. sphere, Euclidean/hyperbolic plane). Similar wrapping might be possible in the spherical and hyperbolic case. I am not sure what this does to vertex-transitivity, but I am optimistic that it is preserved. I might edit the answer later.